# minipage inside multirow in tabular

Tags: tables, multirow

The following example `mc.tex` (found on the web) works (`pdflatex` on Linux/Debian/unstable, `Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian` and `LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5) (preloaded format=pdflatex)`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Partial horizontal line}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{multi-col-row}}&\\
    \cline{1-2}
    X1&X2&X3\\
    Y1&Y2&Y3\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

but the similar example `mc1.tex` below does not work:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Partial horizontal line}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
          \smallskip

          \textbf{\Large XX}

          here is yyyyy text
        \end{minipage}
    }}&\\
    \cline{1-2}
    X1&X2&X3\\
    Y1&Y2&Y3\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
 % pdflatex mc1.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mc1.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty) (./mc1.aux)
Runaway argument?
{\begin {minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth } \smallskip 
! Paragraph ended before \@xmultirow was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.15     }}
           &\\
```

How to have a minipage inside a multirow in tabular?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that while `\multirow` itself might be a long macro, it passes its arguments on to `\@multirow` which is not defined `\long`, so it can't take any `\par` or empty rows in its argument. The offending part is therefore not your `minipage` but the two `\par` tokens contained in it (the empty rows). One can trick this parsing rule by using `\endgraf` instead of `\par` (`\endgraf` then expands to `\par`). So the following works without issues:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Partial horizontal line}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
          \smallskip
          \endgraf
          \textbf{\Large XX}
          \endgraf
          here is yyyyy text
        \end{minipage}
    }}&\\
    &\\
    &\\
    &\\
    \cline{1-2}
    X1&X2&X3\\
    Y1&Y2&Y3\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If your only contents of those two columns is a `minipage`, it might be a better idea to use a `p` type cell in `\multicolumn` though (`\multicolumn` is defined `\long` so can take `\par` tokens directly):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Partial horizontal line}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.2\textwidth}}{
          \smallskip

          \textbf{\Large XX}

          here is yyyyy text
    }&\\
    \cline{1-2}
    X1&X2&X3\\
    Y1&Y2&Y3\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you have saved my day!